# Can I make changes to my database through the Heroku Rails Console in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

This is a noob question, but I wanted to know if I can go into Heroku rails console and make permanent changes to the database? Or is the console in sandbox mode by default and any changes made are reverted back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the following command to make permanent changes to the database

**heroku run rails c**

Answer (score 5):

Running a heroku rails console gives you an access to production database.
To do it:

```
heroku run rails c
```

You can verify, your environment, by running a ruby command in your console:

```
Rails.env
```

Comment: Yes, but does this mean any changes made will "stick" in the production database? Or will they revert back like they do in sandbox mode in development?

Comment: If you proceed the update/save methods everything will be saved in production database. And you can use it with your app. BTW, you usually have to load seed data to your application. So you can do it via console, or a better solution via rake db:seed